# MegaCLI RAID1 - Can't Replace Missing Disk

Tags: raid, storage, hardware-raid, raid1, megacli

I have a RAID1 where I've replaced a disk with errors, however it will not automatically or allow me to manually replace the "missing" disk with the new one.

Here are the physical disks per my controller:

```
# MegaCli64 -PDList -aALL | grep -E 'Enclosure Device ID|Slot Number|Firmware state|Foreign State'

Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Foreign State: None 

Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 1
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Foreign State: None
```

Here is the list of missing disks:

```
# MegaCli64 -Pdgetmissing -a0

Adapter 0 - Missing Physical drives

No.   Array   Row   Size Expected
0     0       0     285148 MB
```

Normally, the new disk will automatically replace the missing one and start rebuilding. I can try to start it my self, however it fails, saying the device does not exist:

```
# MegaCli64 -PdReplaceMissing -physdrv[64:0] -array0 -row0 -a0

Adapter: 0: Failed to replace Missing PD at Array 0, Row 0.

FW error description: 
 The requested command cannot be completed, as the specified device does not exist.
```

Here is full query of the physical disks:

```
Adapter #0

Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 10
WWN: 50000394C8031F29
Seq uence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 264.312 GB [0x210a055e Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 263.812 GB [0x20fa055e Sectors]
Coerced Size: 263.563 GB [0x20f20800 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 6209
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x50000394c8031f2a
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data: IBM     MK3001GRRB      62095360DG92620962096209
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE  Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No

Enclosure Device ID: 64
Slot Number: 1
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 8
WWN: 5000CCA04352785F
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 279.396 GB [0x22ecb25c Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 278.896 GB [0x22dcb25c Sectors]
Coerced Size: 278.464 GB [0x22cee000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: J2EG
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000cca04352785d
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: IBM-ESXSHUC109030CSS60  J2EGKQHGB0USJ2EGJ2EGJ2EG
IBM FRU/CRU: 42D0628     
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :39C (102.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: Unknown 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No

Exit Code: 0x00
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what else I could try?

Comment: Is the replacement drive of the same size and using the same interface?

Comment: Yep, it's the same size (300GB) and using the same interface (SAS).

Comment: To add, I've noticed that the new disk is reporting "Drive: Not Supported", while the active, online disk is reporting "Drive: Not Certified". Trying to find out exactly what this means..

Comment: please post the entire output from "megacli -PDList -aALL"

Comment: Ok, I just updated my main post with the full output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your replacement drive is smaller than the original one: 264.312 GB vs 279.396 GB. You need a drive of the same size or bigger. It must have the same number of sectors or more.

Comment: Hmm, the technician that was dispatched to replace the drive (this is a remote site) replaced a 300GB disk with another 300GB disk. I'm having another dispatched with an even bigger drive to see what happens. I'm trying to put the disk in JBOD mode, however even that is failing. The command `MegaCli64 -PDMakeJBOD -PhysDrv[64:0] -aALL` results in `Adapter: 0: Failed to change PD state at EnclId-64 SlotId-0`.

Comment: @azurepancake yes you can't do anything with this drive as it is unsupported. My bet is that it's a 520 bytes sector drive, hence the difference in apparent size.